# Add custom values in drop down in laravel backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-backpack

I am using laravel back and and I have two tables called bundles and study. I added a drop down fields in the form from bundleCrudController. But I just want to add only those values in the drop down list which studies are created by the logged in user not all the data from studies table.

Here is my code to add data in drop down list -

```
  $this->crud->addField([
                'name' => 'studies',
                'label' => 'Studies',
                'type' => 'select2_from_array',
                'options' => $this->Study->getUnallocatedStudies($entryId),
                'allows_null' => false,
                'hint' => 'Search for the studies you would like to add to this bundle',
                'tab' => 'Info',
                'allows_multiple' => true
            ]);

      $this->crud->addColumn([
                'label' => 'Studies',
                'type' => "select_multiple",
                'name' => 'bundle_id',
                'entity' => 'studies',
                'attribute' => 'name',
                'model' => "App\Models\Study",
            ]);
```

So pls help me to resolve the problem to add only those records in the dropdownlist created by the logged in user not all records.. Thanx

Comment: use model_function or create a custom field in resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/fields and add the condition there or in the studies model (or whatever model you need)  add a global scope (check the manual for all these solutions)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to create an additional model, UserStudy, that:

- extends Study;
- has a global scope for filtering for what the current user can see;

It should look something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Study;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class UserStudy extends Study
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        // filter out the studies that don't belong to this user
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            static::addGlobalScope('user_id', function (Builder $builder) use ($user) {
                $builder->where('user_id', $user->id);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You'll then be able to use this UserStudy model in your field definition, instead of Study. Just replace `App\Models\Study` with `App\Models\UserStudy`.

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thanx dear.. Will try it.